# Does the process get activated or suspended?

Tags: process, vhdl, fpga

I am still having a little bit of trouble understanding the sensitivity list and it activating a process. 
most textbooks say that a process is activated every time an event occurs on a signal inside the sensitivity list.

```
process(in)
begin
    x <= in;
end process;
```

Now looking at this example, "in" is an input declared in the entity. Now if "in" starts off at 0 and changes to 1 then the process would activate and the value of x would take in value "in". Now suppose after in changed from 0 to 1 that it now stays at constant value of 1. Does this mean the process will not get activated? Will x still give output of '1'? I want to say that it wont get activated and will only activate once in changes back from 1 back to 0. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Isn't `in` a reserved word or something?

Comment: It is, but I assumed he just wanted to use it as an example. @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the sensitivity list (I assume this is hardware language, VHDL has the same exact syntax and format), whenever there is some type of signal change (L-> H, 0 ->1, 1-> 0... any change in the variable you listed within the sensitivity list), it will activate the process and the process will execute until completion, which then the process will end. When the process end, signals/outputs (depends on how you interpret them) will be stored on a driver, which will update given signals after some propagation delay.

So from your second statement, yes. If it changes to 0 -> 1, the process activates, if its 1 -> 0, the process activates, and if **in** remains 1, the process will not be activated. So x's value remains.

Comment: Yes it is VHDL, but THank you!!